# SPA example with Web Api and AngularJS in typescript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, typescript

Currently trying to get my head around SPAs with AngularJS written in Typescript, but I have a hard time finding any good examples on how to get things working.

I created a simple MVC5 application with a single 'main page' MVC controller (which, duh, delivers the main page including a layout) where I'm then bootstrapping angularJS and my app:

#### _Layout.cshtml

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
...
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/angular")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/ng-app")
```

#### Client/MyApp.app.ts

```
module MyApp {

    var dependencies = [
        "ngRoute"
    ];

    function configuration($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", { templateUrl: "/" })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
    }

}
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp ' is not available!
```

The few examples I found yet load their applications using:

```
angular.module('todomvc', [])
    .controller('todoCtrl', TodoCtrl)
```

However my main reference application which I'm currently learning from does not: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/src/MusicStore.Spa

So, how to get a simple application working with AngularJS and typescript and why does the ASP.NET MusicStore SPA example does not need to load AngularJS modules with angular.module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with [Hot Towel SPA](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/) by John Papa?
I think it is a very good way to scruture an Angular App.
Found some TypeScript implementations.

[TypeTowel](https://github.com/Svakinn/TypeTowel)

[HotTowel-Angular-TypeScript](https://github.com/johnnyreilly/HotTowel-Angular-TypeScript)

Maybe you can find some interesting info in those projects

Answer (score 0):

Although my 6502 emulator is a bit dated (older versions of Angular and TypeScript), the concepts are still the same. It's a full app written using TypeScript with tests included. The source and documentation are all here:

http://t6502.codeplex.com/

Main bootstrap code (exposes the various modules as static module properties to access throughout)

```
module Main {
    export class App {
        public static Filters: ng.IModule = angular.module("app.filters", []);
        public static Directives: ng.IModule = angular.module("app.directives", []);        
        public static Services: ng.IModule = angular.module("app.services", []);
        public static Controllers: ng.IModule = angular.module("app.controllers", ["app.services"]);    
        public static Module: ng.IModule = angular.module("app", 
            ["app.filters", "app.directives", "app.services", "app.controllers"]);    
    }
}
```